# Sorting discrete x axis in ggplot based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I want to create a visualization to show the racial composition of 600 classrooms in an ordered stacked bar plot. X would be the classrooms, there would be 600 vertical stacked bars with percent of each race represented by different colors. It would be sorted so that you can see roughly how many classrooms have a certain composition.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to order the x-axis based on multiple variables (to sort by race 1, then race, 2, etc.).

Here is some reproducible code with what I have tried.

```
teacher <- c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 6))
studentrace <- c(rep("blk", 3), rep("white", 6), rep("latinx", 3), 
rep("blk", 7), rep("white", 3))
my.df <- data.frame(teacher, studentrace)

library(dplyr)
bars <- my.df %>%
  group_by(teacher, studentrace) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  mutate(percent=n/sum(n))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bars, aes(x=teacher, y=percent)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=studentrace))

#best solution so far, but won't sort using multiple variables
ggplot(bars, aes(x=reorder(teacher, PERCENTWHITE), y=percent)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=studentrace))

#where percent white is a variable I merged into my longform dataset
```

Here is what I got...but I want to be able to sort by x, then y, then z...
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zDX5eRGZlo2vf33WNlz74ybWSuaxO8jp/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: that link is denied access for me. can you just include it as a picutre? also what is PERCENTWHITE?

Comment: I just changed permissions... so it should work.  I can't post a picture until I have a better "reputation"...

Comment: The data frame as written is in long form so it's teacher, race, percent. I merged in a second variable representing percent white students in the classroom, so that each row has a value. I was thinking that I could use it to sort the teachers... but ideally want to sort using all racial composition variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make the order you want before to call `gglot`, directly in your dataset, with the function `arrange()` (this way you can sort according several variables), and then use in the `aes()` of your ggplot the function `fct_inorder()` from **forçats** library, in order to keep the same order as in your dataset.